# Angular JS module sharing between different projects

Tags: angularjs, typescript, namespaces

I have two angular with typescript projects, and I want one module (namespace in fact) to be available for both.

In project one, I have a module with a controller and a service. I want this functionality available in my second project, without copying the code.

Is it as simple as exporting the module and injecting it as a dependency on my new project?

I have tried this solution, but I have not succeeded. This is my code:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>

namespace Controllers {
"use strict";
    export class ExampleCtrl {

       public static $inject: Array<string> = [];

       private attrs;

       constructor() {
       // Stuff here
       }

       // Public and private methods, here
   }
angular.module("app.exampleCtrl").controller("ExampleCtrl", Controllers.ExampleCtrl);
}
```

How can I access this controller in my second project? I try this:

```
import {ExampleCtrl} from "../../directory/ExampleCtrl";
```

But TS linter shows an error that the module is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is that easy. You just need to call your module and its components (controllers, services, etc...) and inject them as a dependency in your new project.